# Can't login into GitHub account from IntelliJ-like IDE

Tags: github, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I don't understand what's wrong. On stable branch (not EAP) the same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a problem: the wrong default browser is installed on the system

Answer (score 0):

Please contact PhpStorm support via Help | Contact Support attaching your logs (Help > Show log in ..). Not much I can advise right now: no similar reports on our end.